# In C# Web API - how do I get User and Pass from Python HTTPBasicAuth

Tags: c#, python, basic-authentication

In the following Python call, how do I get User and Pass from Python HTTPBasicAuth on the C# Web API side?

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
s = requests.Session()

# Make the initial authentication request from a session object
s.get('https://omg.wtf/user', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))

# All subsequent requests from that session will include any cookies set in the initial response
r = s.get('http://omg.wtf/911')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest(v=vs.110).aspx

HttpRequest headers collection should contain the basic auth data if it's sent in plain text.

Comment: mmmm - not finding it yet

Comment: Should be in {Request.Headers["Authorization"]}